# How to get image from path

Tags: objective-c

I downloaded the image using `afnetworking` and save the name `[response suggestedFilename]`; I can't get image from path.

Here is the download methods:

```
- (void)startDownload:(OMImageTableViewCell *)cell {

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[_arrayImages objectAtIndex:cell.download.tag]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:60];

[cell.imagePic setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:cell.imagePic.image success:nil failure:nil];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull downloadProgress) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell.progressDownload setProgress:downloadProgress.fractionCompleted];
    });

}  destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

    _documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    return [_documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imagePic.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    });

    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];

}
```

Comment: How do you trying to get image? Paste some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL isFileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: filePath];
UIImage *image;
if (isFileExist) {
    image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
}
else {
    // do something.
}
```

Comment: It did not help. I want to pull them in uitableviewcell to reflect only downloaded pictures.

Comment: Maybe you need this framework: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage. Just #import the UIImageView+WebCache.h header, and call the sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage: method from the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: UITableViewDataSource method. Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching management.